# Global object with functions to be overriden by each project JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global

I'm wondering how I should design my javascript files.

I will have a `global.js` file which will be used for all projects. Then each project will have it's own `project.js` file, containing specific functions/overrides/settings just for that project.

So I'll want to write all my "global" functions in the **global.js** file:

```
Global = function() {
    var config = {'alpha': 1};

    function getConfig() {
        return this.config;
    }

    function printConfig() {
        console.log(this.getConfig());
    }
};

Global.prototype.echoConfig = function() {
    console.log(this.getConfig());
};
```

and I guess my **project.js** file, would look like:

```
var project = new Global();

Global.prototype.projFunc = function() { return 2; };
```

However, I haven't figured out how to get the config from `global.js` ?

I'm using jQuery, and have noted there's the $.extend function that looks nice, however I'd like to first set-up the structure for my global.js and project.js - in general I'd probably want to move most functions from project.js into global.js, but there might be one or two projects that only need 1 specific function for that application.

Comment: It may be worth Instantiating `Global` at the end of `global.js`. `var global = new Global();`. `global` will be globally accessible in all other javascript.

Comment: @IanBrindley, so instead of doing var project = new Global(); in each project.js (bear in mind, each project only includes it's own project.js file -> public/[project]/js/project.js) - then just add it to the one global.js file? Hmm, seems better idea, I'll implement it, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have `getConfig` in a public scope, and since you have `config` declared in a "private" way, you cannot use `this.config` to get the `config`, just use `config`.

```
Global = function() {
    var config = {'alpha': 1};

    this.getConfig = function() {
        return config;
    }

    function printConfig() {
        console.log(this.getConfig());
    }
};
```

[Scope Tutorial](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)